# Read FTP file contents in Python and use it at the same time for Pandas and directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to download a file from an FTP server in memory, transform it to a dataframe but also return it as bytes. Code as follows:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from ftplib import FTP

ftp_connection.cwd(ftp_folder)
download_file = io.BytesIO()
ftp_connection.retrbinary('RETR ' + str(file_name), download_file.write)
download_file.seek(0)
file_to_process = pd.read_csv(download_file, engine='python')
```

After searching on Stack Overflow, the suggestion was to just read the io stream:

```
download_file.read()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Not sure what to try next, without writing the file somewhere and reading it again as bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_csv` probably closes the "file". So read it before you call `read_csv`:

```
download_file.seek(0)
contents = download_file.read()
download_file.seek(0)
file_to_process = pd.read_csv(download_file, engine='python')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. I was stuck for ages with a "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file" error and the key was to seek(0) first

Answer (score 1):

I think that's easier with tentaclio package :

```
with tentaclio.open("ftp://user:password@host/path/name_file.csv") as reader:
    df = pd.read_csv(reader)
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64680992/edit) and consider explaining the code a little.