# How to Read a CSV file into a dataframe from FTP in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file, ftp

I am really new as to the file reading aspects of Python and FTP combination. I searched all over the google and Stack but could not find a working solution for my ask.

My Ask is below.

I have an FTP location - dummy details below.

1. Location: ftp.xyz.com
2. username: random
3. password: password
4. File Name:testreport.csv
5. filepath:rootfolder/testfolder/

The file has 20 columns and 10000 rows of data

I am looking to create a dataframe 'df' that will have all the rows captured from the testreport.csv file using Python.Is there a way to directly post it into the datframe rather than downloading it first?

Is there a code I can use for this? I am using Python 3.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? I can see plenty of leads just by typing "*read a file from FTP/SFTP python*" in google

Comment: What about this? [Read FTP file contents in Python and use it at the same time for Pandas and directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58320638/850848)

Comment: Hi @anky_91, thank you for the help. I couldnt find any that was csv related nor it involves dataframes or directly storing than downloading

Answer (score 1):

20 columns and 10000 rows is not so huge, so except if you are working on an embedded system with tiny storage, the simplest way is to just download the file with `ftplib` and then load it into a dataframe with `read_csv` (see NicolasDupuy's answer).

If you really and for any reason want to avoid to store it on the local disk, it will be a little trickyer because pandas `read_csv` is not able to read from a stream and requires a plain file. That means that you will have to parse the file *by hand* or only with the `csv` module, and then feed a dataframe from that.

Code could be:

```
import csv
import ftplib
import pandas as pd

FTP = ftplib.open('ftp.xyz.com', 'random', 'password')
FTP.cwd('rootfolder/testfolder')

first = True     # to identify the header line
data = []
columns = None

def process_row(line):
    global columns
    if first:
        columns = parse(line)
        first = False
    else:
        data.append(parse(line))

def parse(line):
    # Assume trivial csv file here - use the csv module for more complex use cases
    return line.decode().strip().split(',')

FTP.retrline('RETR testreport.csv', process_row)

df = pd.Dataframe(data = data, columns = columns)
# or for automatic conversion to float:
# df = pd.Dataframe(data = data, columns = columns, dtype = float)
```

Beware:

- above code is untested and can contain typos...
- above code contains no exception processing and will be unsafe if given incorrect input
- as you cannot use `read_csv` you have no magical guess of the colum types

Said differently: unless you have a strong reason to do so, do not use that and just download the file first....

Comment: I'm not sure you are right – `read_cvs` accepts a file-like object. See [Read FTP file contents in Python and use it at the same time for Pandas and directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58320638/850848) (I've already posted this link at the question).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Well it accepts a file-like object but AFAIK requires it to be seekable, what is hardly obtained from a ftp stream.

Comment: But you can download the contents to `BytesIO` or `StringIO` and you do not need all that `process_row`/`parse` machinery. This is what the code in the referenced question does. I believe it does the same what your code, but in 4 lines only.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl; You are right. This solution is interesting only because it demonstrate how to process the stream *on the flight* without requiring the file to be fully downloaded. But it is almost useless when the goal is to put that in a pandas dataframe... Anyway I will let the answer for the *on the flight* part.

Comment: Your answer would be useful, had it process the file line-by-line into Pandas. Then it would be more efficient, as it would prevent having the file twice in the memory (once as an unparsed text and once parsed in Pandas).